# Mapping undefined json properties

Tags: php, json, slim

Can anyone suggest me a good practice for mapping json decoded objects into pdo statements in a clean way?

I've created a api (using [slim](https://www.slimframework.com) and [slim-pdo](https://github.com/FaaPz/Slim-PDO)) for crud operations requested from different client apps.
Some tables are quite big with several nullable columuns. 
This means that for most cases the posted json will not be complete with all column data.

exemple:

```
    $item= json_decode($req->getBody());
    $insertStatement = $pdo->insert(array('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3',..., 'prop10'))
                           ->into('table')
                           ->values(array($item->prop1, $item->prop2, $item->prop3,..., 'server side value 10') ));
```

when posting from client something like this...

{"prop" : "foo" , "prop2" : "bar"}

...php logs a warning like this:

PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$prop3 in /home/... on line ...

As prop3 is not present in json.

I know this can be avoided by using php [property_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) and/or [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).
However, doing it for all properties in all statements of dozens of operations code will become huge and messy.

I've googled for a clean solution for this.
Initially by searching a way of undefined properties act as null.
Then searching for object mapping approach.

Any suggestion?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: If using PHP 7, you can use the Null Coalesce operator ??, so `$item->prop3??null` will set the value to null if not there.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
$json = '{"prob": "foo", "prop2": "bar"}';
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);// this will decode json in array
// $jsonArray will be: ["prop" => "foo", "prop2" => "bar"]
// array_keys will be: ["prop", "prop2"]
// array_values wil be: ["foo", "bar"];

$insertStatement = $pdo->insert(array_keys($jsonArray))
                           ->into('table')
                           ->values(array_values($jsonArray));
```